# jQuery slideDown, IE7 bug when child has position:relative

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Simple example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CnUkA/5/

I have an outer div which the slideDown animation is applied to, and inside this div is an inner div with `position:relative`.

The inner div displays immediately when you click the button is IE7. In the real world where I'm using this I need that div to be relative to I can position children inside it with absolute.

**--- EDIT ---**

Using `position:absolute` on `#slide` isn't suitable in my situation.

I will have elements absolutely positioned relative to the `#inner` div so I can't remove `position:relative` from that either.

Here's an updated example showing why I need `position:relative` on `#inner`.
http://jsfiddle.net/CnUkA/9/

Both the relative and absolute elements show before the slide animate has completed in IE7

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Using a combination of the answers below I think this is a decent solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/CnUkA/13/

Add `position:relative` to the div that is sliding down, then set `position:static` once the animation completes. This prevents the element from disappearing.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your solution. I thought the problem is that the inner div *displays* immediately. (At least that is what you wrote in the beginning, and that is the problem I am having, too.) Your solution, on the other hand, "prevents the element from disappearing". I thought the solution should be to make the element disappear until the animation has progressed far enough.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the child displays immediately because the offset parent is not the `#slide` div.

If you set `position: relative;` on the `#slide` div it works better, but for some reason the last three lines disappear after the slide.

If you set `position: absolute;` on the `#slide` div it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but not really suitable for my needs to use `position:absolute` on `#slide`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way, i have test in my IE browser

```
Remove-  #inner position:relative property And Update your jQuery script also

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

         $("#slide").slideDown(2000, function()
         { 
         $("#inner").css("position","relative");
         });

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Might be a useful method. The content inside that div will change, so I don't know exactly what elements are set to relative and position. I could be careful and always use the same class names so that before slide animation change the position of these classes to static and after the slide has completed change them back to relative / absolute.  Only problem is elements will jump around a bit after the slide has finished

Comment: please post your website link

Comment: Website is not in public domain. I've updated my question with the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

just add position absolute to

```
#slide{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not really suitable for my needs to use `position:absolute` on `#slide`